# jQuery email has no text/submits twice

Tags: php, javascript, email, jquery

I am trying to simply send an email to a hardcoded email address as a function of a report bug button. However, the text I try to input to the php file that sends the email wont transmit through, and the email function in my javascript file is sending two emails at once. Not sure why either of these are happening.

Here is all my code pertaining to the email function.

Bug page (HTML)

```
<div data-role="page" id="bug">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Submit a bug</h4>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
        <a href="#first" data-icon="check" data-role="button" data-inline="true" name="send" id="send">Send</a>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $("#send").click(function(){
            email();
            });
            function clearText()
            {
                $('textarea#textarea').val('');
            }           
        </script>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</di> <!-- /bug -->
```

The above page is called when a user hits the "report bug button", which looks like this:

`<a href='#bug' data-rel="dialog" onclick="clearText()" data-close-btn="left" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Report bug</a>`

Javascript file with email function:

```
function email(){

var name = "Joey"; 
var email = "example@gmail.com"
var vardata = $("textarea").val();

$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "email.php", data: vardata, success: function() {
alert("Your bug report was sent!");
        }
});

return false;
}
```

and my PHP file that is called:

```
<?php

$message = $_POST["vardata"];

mail("example@gmail.com", "Mystery person", $message);
?>
```

If the $message field is hardcoded in, I can get text in the emails just fine, but it can't grab it from the vardata tag. Also, it submits twice, as you can see [here](http://psc.carthage.edu/tests/yup.html). Just click the report bug button and hit send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send data to PHP through jQuery's ajax method, it's helpful to make it a JSON object, so you can get the values you need from the $_POST array in your PHP.

For example:

```
var name = "Joey"; 
var email = "example@gmail.com"
var vardata = $("textarea").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php",
    data: {name:name, email:email, vardata:vardata}, 
    success: function() {
        alert("Your bug report was sent!");
    }
});
```

In this way, you can get the data in your PHP code like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['vardata'];
```

Comment: This answer worked! The text is now showing up!

I think it was because of your grouping of all the fields into the "data" variable. Thank you so much to everyone! You all contributed something and helped :)

Answer (score 3):

In your PHP file you are getting the `$_POST["vardata"]`, but in your javascript the field is called `data`. So use `$_POST["data"]` instead.

Comment: `data` is the [JQuery name for sending data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and not the name of the field being sent to the server.

Comment: This doesn't work... I'm still getting no text in the emails :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm used to using `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`. In the post, you don't have to set the type, and he content between the curly brackets is as I said it was. Got it mixed up, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

while analyzing the `console` panel it seems there are two `ajax` calls made this is because `id="send"` has a click event attached twice

So here is the trick to do first `unbind` all the click events on `id="send"` anchor then attach the click event which will resolve the twice email problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#send").unbind("click");
$("#send").click(function(){
 email();
});
});
```

Comment: This worked for the sending twice issue! Thank you :) I wish I could pick two correct answers..

Comment: That's certainly valid, but that's a workaround to a bug that he is facing. If he does not know what is wiring them, then it's only a matter of time before there are three click events.  Similarly, you can chain those calls: `$("#send").unbind("click").click(...);` to avoid potential DOM lookups.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the data to the server with a name:

```
$.ajax({ /* ... */, data: {vardata: vardata}});
```

As for the double sending, you are wiring the `click` event twice, although I do not see where the second event is wired, but I suspect that it is autogenerated and then thrown away once.

You can see events wired by calling `jQuery._data($("#send")[0], "events");` in your debug console. Two events are wired and both handler functions are identical (they call `email();`).